# switch pages using AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good day all, I'm working on a jquery game and I'm making a welcome screen. I'm using ajax to switch pages. So far the pages are switching exactly but the page `index.php` where game's elements are running has stopped working and no animation is working. Here are the codes:

`welcome.php` script:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function swapContent(cv) {
            var url = "page-switch.php";
            $.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
                $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con1');">Play!</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con2');">Scoreboard</a>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

`page-switch.php` script:

```
<?php 
    $contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
        if ($contentVar == "con1") {
            header('Location: index.php');
        } else if ($contentVar == "con2") {
            header('Location: score-post.php');
    }
?>
```

`index.php` script:

```
<head>
    <title>Space Game Test 01</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-collision.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core-animation.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/content-style.css">
</head>

<body onload="start()">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="galaxy"><img src="images/galaxy.png" /><img src="images/galaxy.png" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="linkpanel"></div>
    <div id="scoreboard">Score<br><div id="score">0</div><input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause" /><br>
    <input type="button" id="resume" value="Resume" /></div>
    <script>
        var pause = null;

        $("#resume").click(function () {
            if(!pause)
            {
                pause = setInterval(scroll_ns, 50)
            }
        });

        $("#pause").click(function () {
            clearInterval(pause);
            pause = null;
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty noob in ajax but I really need to learn. Please help! Tnx.

Comment: You're missing semi-colons at the end of `pause` and `resume` on click functions (and on the `pause = ` statement in `resume` on click function) . I can't see your ajax code or the rest of your js code such as `start()` function. can you post `core-animation.js`?

Comment: You are not exiting the script after calling header location. you need to do that otherwise the script continues to run.

Comment: @alez007, how can I exit the scipt?

Comment: @SinOscuras

header('Location: index.php');
exit();

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use load function also

<script>
    function swapContent(page) {
        jQuery( "#myDiv" ).load(page);
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('index.php');">Play!</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('score.php');">Scoreboard</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this you have to redirect to the page after getting response from ajax.

```
<script>
function swapContent(cv) {
var url = "page-switch.php";
$.post(url, {contentVar: cv} ,function(data) {
   //alert(data)
  if(data="first"){
      window.location.href = "index.php";
  }
  if(data="second"){
    window.location.href = "score.php";
  }
});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con1');">Play!</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="swapContent('con2');">Scoreboard</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>

page-switch.php script:

<?php 
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if ($contentVar == "con1") {
 echo "first";
} else if ($contentVar == "con2") {
 echo "second";
}
?>
```

Comment: first check what is you are getting in response by alert the data.and then check the file path inside window.location,href(); must be correct..

Comment: now page is changing. But whether its first or second it'll only load any one of the page. And it seems like page is refreshing. But I want to change page without browser refreshing!

Comment: so don't use window.loaction.href(); you can load the page by using load method like .load("index.php");